# How to say something seemed like it was out of the blue?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasing

> Then, in what seemed like it was out of the blue, they started to interact.

This is what I'm trying to say but it's definitely phrased wrong. How should this be phrased?

Comment: You need to give more context, your sentence is too abstract. Why _in what_? Who are they, and what kind of interaction?

Comment: do you want it to be funny, serious, etc... what is the mood and what will this interaction lead to? I think is all important questions in order to set the mood sorta saying.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, **unexpectedly**, they started to interact.

Springs to mind immediately. You could also substitute **surprisingly**, **out of nowhere**, or, my favorite: **apropos of nothing**.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use that expression you can say

> Then, [out of the blue](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+blue), they started to interact.

More safely you can say

> They unexpectedly started to interact.

But it depends on the context, and *how* unexpected it was. Don't throw in a metaphor without good reason. I've read non-native English language newspapers that throw in all the supposedly relevant metaphors the writer knows, but the copy doesn't usually work very well.

Comment: You can add another word to the sentence. "Then, **quite** unexpectedly, they started to interact".